# How to pass objects of an array of objects as list of comma seperated objects to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm using a function that expects a comma separated list of objects as parameters.
What I actually have is an array of objects.

```
var my_array_of_objects = [{"bla":bla, "blub":blub, ...},{"bla":bla, "blub":blub, ...},{"bla":bla, "blub":blub, ...}, ...];
var variable = my_function(object, object);
```

It should be really simple but I couldn't figure it out.
The `join(',')` function converts the objects into strings, so that's not what I need. I also tried something with the `map()` function but without success so far. Can anyone provide a tip or a solution maybe?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'comma separated list of objects'. Why not just pass the array to the function?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @Rory: The function doesn't expect an array, it expects several objects separated by commas. I also can't rewrite the function because it's a minified third party script. But the apply-Method provided by Hindmost and Piyush seemed to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is

```
function hello(obj1,obj2) {
}
```

then Do this

```
hello.apply(this,my_array_of_objects)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! And Hindmost who provided the answer in as comment as well. This did the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to convert it to Json 
`JSON.stringify(my_array_of_objects);`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the array using spread operator.

> [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply)
>
> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.

```js
let args = [{"bla":"bla", "blub":"blub"},{"bla":"bla", "blub":"blub"},{"bla":"bla", "blub":"blub"}];

let your_fn = (a, b, c) => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
}

your_fn(...args);
```